# how to check disk partition in Ubuntu 12.10 and do partition for other OS

Tags: disk

I want to check my disk partition in Ubuntu as i want to install windows OS and create partition

Comment: You've got two questions here that can't be answered at the same time.  One about checking your partitions within Ubuntu, and another about installing Windows.  Those are completely separate questions, and I suggest you split off the question about installing Windows into a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you want is GParted. Which is the recommended tool for managing partitions. To install it just look at your Software Center for gparted, or type in a terminal `sudo apt-get install gparted`. It shows visually the current status of your disks partitions.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use disk utility feature in ubuntu for checking the hard disk partition